# CSS: how to align last elem to the left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Due to the justify-content: space-around rule, when 4th block jumps down, it becomes in the middle

can I somehow still use the space-around rule, but make the last block do not jump to the center, but to the left, like in the screenshot ??
P.S. I still need justify-content: space-around because of it responsive margins

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/s4fbtkyg/

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
  .block{
  background-color: grey;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N5II.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to consider CSS grid for this task using:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px); //100px being the width of your choosing
```

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.block{
  background-color: grey;
}

.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px);
  justify-content: space-around; //you can still use justify-content: space-around

}
```

fiddle: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/k0fy9bh4/)

Comment: the question  is "Can we do it using space-around?" 
but anyway thanks for the reply! will consider your way

Comment: @JackSurma, the code does indeed use justify-content: space-around;

Comment: ohh sorry, you are right! Great! You really helped me out =)